# Android: tools to find memory leaks?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

Are there some useful tools to detect memory leaks in Android Java applications? Something similar to Valgrind where the place of creation of a non-freed object is shown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Watch this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Then install [MAT for Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). Happy hounting!

Answer (score 5):

read this post on Android Developer Blog, it has what you need
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Comment: I know about DDMS and MAT but it definitely is NOT something that is in some way similar to Valgrind. For an example: when I analyse my application I can see huge amounts of Location and Parcel objects. But there is no information where they have been created. Resulting from that I can't find out if these amounts are OK or if it is a problem or who causes them.Is memory leak checking really that poor on Android?

Comment: I'm afraid it is, but will be very happy to see something new in that matter